# Using HATEOAS with JQuery datatables

Tags: datatables, spring-data-rest, hateoas

Having a HTTP rest like API that is rendering HAL responses (like spring-data-rest) i am searching for the best way to integrate an angular client that is using jquery datatables.

Is there any way to do this without lot of work?

I've been searching without success about this topic even when both datatables and spring-data-rest are very popular.

Answer (score 1):

This is a 2 years old question, but here is how to do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* Init the files table */
    var filesTable = $("#tags").DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "ajax": { 
            "url": "/api/v2/tag/search/findCategoryTags",
            "dataSrc": "_embedded.tags"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "id" }
        ]
    });
});
```

Use the `dataSrc` property for the Ajax. More info [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc).

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems here is that you need to deal with the incompatibility of the pagination and sorting scheme on the spring-data-rest (HAL) and Datatables. Take a look at the `function datatable2Rest (...)` in this link:

https://github.com/gcase/spring-data-rest-datatable-example/blob/master/spring-data-rest-datatables.md